# RestTemplate Request/Response simple JSON-String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Does any body have samples of SpringBoot - RequestTemplate for get/post a simple raw JSON Template like below  example

Request
http://localhost:8080/SpringTest/check?JsonToTest={"name":"charlie","type":"clown"}

Response
{"name":"charlie","type":"clown","age":"35","country":"JPA"}

Yahooed/Googled ,... but not able to find the simple Json-String example...

with regards
Karthik

Comment: Did you mean `RestTemplate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea for your implements.
I have some suggestion as follows:

1.HTTP Get Method(pass value by key=value in url path)
You can't pass the Json-String in common use.

2.Use of RestTemplate

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("name", "charlie")
        .queryParam("type", "clown")
        .queryParam("age", "35")
        .queryParam("country", "JPA");


HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        builder.build().encode().toUri(), 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        entity, 
        String.class);
```